# How mapping works reading data to DataTable by Load() from DataReader in .NET?

Tags: .net, datatable, datareader

I am using firebird .NET provider and when I do something like this:

```
DataTable.Load(FbCommand.ExecuteReader());
```

I will get some, probably mapping, queries to server in debug output. Is it true, using this tools this way produce this mapping queries to sql servers? Debug output [snippet is here](http://pastebin.com/QDrDkqGa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I made some profiling and found this:

- on SQL Server this produce only one query
- on Firebird this produce FbCommand query and then other extra commands depending on num of columns